# How can I profile cache hits with lodash memoize?

Tags: javascript, lodash, memoization

I have memoized lodash function that takes an object as its argument. When this function gets called, how can I tell how often its hitting the cache vs evaluating the function with new arguments?

Answer (score 2):

If you're just doing it in development, you can do something like count the number of times cache.get is called vs how many times the function is called. Something like

```js
var calls = 0;
var hits = 0;

function test(b) {
  calls += 1;
  return b + 1;
}

var mem_test = _.memoize(test);

mem_test.cache.get = function(n) {
  var cached = mem_test.cache.get;
  calls += 1;
  hits += 1;
  return function() {
    var result = cached.call(this, n);
    return result;
  }
}
mem_test(1);
mem_test(2);
mem_test(2);
console.log(calls);
console.log(hits);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

That simple example should output 3 and 1.

Comment: thanks - I did only need this in development so this approach worked for me.